# Getting not-null constraint violation in hibernate when trying to save an entity with a joined column in Spring

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I am receiving a not-null constraint violation when trying to save an entity and can't figure out exactly what my annotations and class definitions need to be to make this work.

My database consists of movies that have a one-to-many relationship with ratings. The tables and classes are defined as follows:

Movie:

```
   Column    |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 movie_id    | character varying(15)  |           | not null |
 title       | character varying(250) |           | not null |
 year        | integer                |           |          |
 runningtime | integer                |           |          |
Indexes:
    "movie_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (movie_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "rating" CONSTRAINT "rating_movie_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movie(movie_id)
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movie")
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "movie_id")
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private Integer year;
    @Column(name = "runningtime")
    private Integer runningTime;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="movie", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Rating> ratings;

    public Movie(String id, String title, Integer year, Integer runningTime) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.year = year;
        this.runningTime = runningTime;
    }

    public Movie() {

    }
```

Rating:

```
   Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                  Default
------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------
 rating_id  | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('rating_rating_id_seq'::regclass)
 movie_id   | character varying(15)       |           | not null |
 rating     | integer                     |           | not null |
 created_at | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
Indexes:
    "rating_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (rating_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "rating_movie_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movie(movie_id)
```

```
@Entity(name = "Rating")
@Table(name = "rating")
public class Rating {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    @Column(name = "rating_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "rating")
    private Double ratingValue;
    @Column(name = "created_at", insertable = false)
    private LocalDateTime time;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id")
    private Movie movie;

    public Rating(String movieId, Double ratingValue) {
        this.ratingValue = ratingValue;
        this.time = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    public Rating() {

    }
```

My RatingController class has the following mapping to save a rating:

```
    @PostMapping
    public void addRating(@RequestBody Rating rating) {
        ratingRepository.save(rating);
    }
```

When my PostMapping triggers, the JSON body received consists of:
`rating: "Rating{id=null, movieId=0119217, ratingValue=9.0, time=null}`
But hibernate is telling me:  `Failing row contains (4, null, 9, null).`

I can see the rating id gets generated before the save happens, as it does have a value of 4 in the error thrown, and the "time" column is handled with a timestamp generation upon creation of the entity in Postgres. However, I can't figure out how to assign a value to movie_id. I had previously kept a private String within Rating, but I realized that was redundant with the join of the columns when the only way to get it to compile was to add `updateable=false, insertable=false` to the movieId column annotation, at which point there was really no reason for it to be there because those annotations would cause spring to not update that value upon the save.

Does anybody know how to configure this so I can save a new rating?

Comment: You must set the value for movie field in Rating before save.

Comment: Ahh, this was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As [svn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/767949/svn) suggested, I had to set the Movie field before I was able to save, so I changed the param for my PostMapping to `@RequestBody Map<String, String> jsonBody`, called `movieRepository.findById(jsonBody.get("movieId")` and set the returned `Movie` field on the rating before saving it. If anyone knows of a more efficient method than this, please let me know, but this works for now!